# Flutter display huge number of images from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, performance, android-studio, flutter

I am developing an application with **Flutter**, and I need to display a large number (more than 1000) of images from firebase in Card widgets (with LazyLoadScrollView)
Note : **The average image size is 320KB**

so I tested:

1. **CachedNetworkImage** :

```
CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: 'url',
                   fit: BoxFit.cover,
                   placeholder: (context, url) =>
                   Image.asset('assets/images/creative.gif'),
                   errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),),
```

It causes a **big performance problem** just after loading 15 to 20 Card (almost = 40 images).

2. **FadeInImage** :

```
FadeInImage.assetNetwork( placeholder: 'assets/images/creative.gif',
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          image:'url',
                        ),
```

Regarding performance it is perfect but **there is no cache**, so it reload images when I scroll up or down (I don't know why: v)

3. **FadeInImage with CachedNetworkImageProvider**:

```
FadeInImage(fit: BoxFit.cover,
            image: new CachedNetworkImageProvider(
            'url',),)
```

Same **performance problem** like CachedNetworkImage.

### Help please!!

Comment: at the moment I'm using `flutter_advanced_networkimage 0.7.0` package in order to cache images and define a clean time span. I load 20/30 images with no problems. Can you please provide a reproducible sample?

Comment: Unfortunately same problem,
In my case I have 17 Card and 38 images
in fact, I succeeded to display all the widgets correctly and there is no more processing to do (no more setstate (), no more rebuild widgets)
so the only thing the app does is scroll and display the photos..
You can find here an extract from my code :
https://github.com/IdrissMiraoui/flutter/blob/master/scroll.dart